# How to create an array of resource Ids with loop

Tags: java, android, android-resources

How can i delare this with loop in array?

```
private int[] inisialSub = {
            R.id.sub0,
            R.id.sub1,
            R.id.sub2,
            R.id.sub3,
            R.id.sub4,
            R.id.sub5,
            R.id.sub6,
            R.id.sub7,
            R.id.sub8,
            R.id.sub9,
            R.id.sub10,
            R.id.sub11,
            R.id.sub12,
            R.id.sub13,
            R.id.sub14,
            R.id.sub15,
            R.id.sub16,
            R.id.sub17,
            R.id.sub18,
            R.id.sub19,
            R.id.sub20,
            R.id.sub21,
            R.id.sub22,
            R.id.sub23,
    };
```

i want to short my code, thankyou verymuch

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Resources.getIdentifier`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method.

```
Resources resources = getResources();
String packageName = getPackageName();

int[] inisialSub = new int[24];
for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
    inisialSub[i] = resources.getIdentifier("sub" + String.valueOf(i), "id", packageName);
}
```